# telegram bot api how to send image with inline buttons?

Tags: php, telegram, php-telegram-bot

As i know method `sendPhoto` dosnt match this question.
I wanna send message with one photo and 3 inline buttons with it.

Is it real? Or i must send two messages (photo and buttons)

I use php

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not clear what you're asking. Could you provide some examples or code you've written so far, and what you're trying to achieve? See [guidelines for asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
if($text == '/send'){
bot('sendPhoto',[
'chat_id'=>$update->message->chat->id,
'photo'=>new CURLFile("path.PNG"),
'caption'=>"HELLO",
'parse_mode'=>"MarkDown",
'disable_web_page_preview'=>true,
'reply_markup'=>json_encode([
'inline_keyboard'=>[
[['text'=>'button 1','callback_data'=>'any']],
[['text'=>'button 2','callback_data'=>'any']],
[['text'=>'button 3','callback_data'=>'any']],
]
])
]);
}
```